# RxSwift :Cannot convert value of type '(_, _, Bool) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(_, _, _) -> _'

Tags: rx-swift

"signingIn : Observable " is for the progress bar and to prevent the user to click the button again before i get the response from the API

```
let validatedUsername: Observable<Bool> 
let validatedPassword: Observable<Bool>
var signingIn : Observable<Bool>    // Is signing process in progress
let signupEnabled: Observable<Bool> //Is signup button enabled

validatedUsername = input.username
        .map { username in
            return username.characters.count > 5
        }
        .shareReplay(1)

validatedPassword = input.password
        .map { password in
            return  password.characters.count > 5
        }
        .shareReplay(1)

signupEnabled = Observable.combineLatest(
        validatedUsername,
        validatedPassword,
        signingIn.asObservable()
    )   { username, password , signing in  //the error at this line

        username.isValid &&
            password.isValid &&
            !signing
        }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .shareReplay(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `validatedUsername` and `validatedPassword` are both of type `Observable<Bool>`, calling `.isValid` on `username` and `password` probably doesn't type check.

The error ends up on the line above because the compiler cannot infer the return type and throws out something earlier. You can try to check if you get a better error message by typing out the parameters and return type of the closure passed to `combineLatest`.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
        validatedUsername,
        validatedPassword,
        signingIn.asObservable()
    )   { (username: Bool, password: Bool, signing: Bool) -> Bool in    
  return username.isValid && password.isValid && !signing
}
```

The error thrown out now should be more obvious and this fix is probably as simple as removing the `.isValid` call

```
return username && password && !signing
```

Comment: Thanks tomahh for your answer!